# Nodes not defined in a matrix of math nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made this example in 2008 and it compiled ([texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/)).

I tried to recompile the code but without success and I can't find the error.

Now some nodes are undefined. I commented the lines with problem

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

% l' unite
\newcommand{\myunit}{1 cm}
\tikzset{
    node style sp/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=\myunit},
    node style ge/.style={circle,minimum size=\myunit},
    arrow style mul/.style={draw,sloped,midway,fill=white},
    arrow style plus/.style={midway,sloped,fill=white},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
% les matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {node style ge},%
             left delimiter  = (,%
             right delimiter = )] at (0,0)
{%
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1p}  \\
  \node[node style sp] {a_{21}};%
         & \node[node style sp] {a_{22}};%
                  & \ldots%
                           & \node[node style sp] {a_{2p}}; \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{np}  \\
};
\node [draw,below=10pt] at (A.south) 
    { $A$ : \textcolor{red}{$n$ rows} $p$ columns};

\matrix (B) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {node style ge},%
             left delimiter  = (,%
             right delimiter =)] at (6*\myunit,6*\myunit)
{%
  b_{11} & \node[node style sp] {b_{12}};%
                  & \ldots & b_{1q}  \\
  b_{21} & \node[node style sp] {b_{22}};%
                  & \ldots & b_{2q}  \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  b_{p1} & \node[node style sp] {b_{p2}};%
                  & \ldots & b_{pq}  \\
};
\node [draw,above=10pt] at (B.north) 
    { $B$ : $p$ rows \textcolor{red}{$q$ columns}};
% matrice résultat
\matrix (C) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {node style ge},%
             left delimiter  = (,%
             right delimiter = )] at (6*\myunit,0)
{%
  c_{11} & c_{12} & \ldots & c_{1q} \\
  c_{21} & \node[node style sp,red] {c_{22}};%
                  & \ldots & c_{2q} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  c_{n1} & c_{n2} & \ldots & c_{nq} \\
};
% les fleches
% \draw[blue] (A-2-1.north) -- (C-2-2.north);
% \draw[blue] (A-2-1.south) -- (C-2-2.south);
% \draw[blue] (B-1-2.west)  -- (C-2-2.west);
% \draw[blue] (B-1-2.east)  -- (C-2-2.east);
% \draw[<->,red](A-2-1) to[in=180,out=90]
%   node[arrow style mul] (x) {$a_{21}\times b_{12}$} (B-1-2);
% \draw[<->,red](A-2-2) to[in=180,out=90]
%   node[arrow style mul] (y) {$a_{22}\times b_{22}$} (B-2-2);
% \draw[<->,red](A-2-4) to[in=180,out=90]
%   node[arrow style mul] (z) {$a_{2p}\times b_{p2}$} (B-4-2);
% \draw[red,->] (x) to node[arrow style plus] {$+$} (y)%
%                   to node[arrow style plus] {$+\raisebox{.5ex}{\ldots}+$} (z)%
%                   to (C-2-2.north west);

\node [draw,below=10pt] at (C.south) 
    {$ C=A\times B$ : \textcolor{red}{$n$ rows}  \textcolor{red}{$q$ columns}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now I get

[image]

With the first line commented

```
Latex Error: ./matrix-multiplication.tex:66 Package pgf Error: No shape named `A-2-1' is known.

Latex Error: ./matrix-multiplication.tex:66 Package pgf Error: No shape named `C-2-2' is known.
```

In 2008

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if it is really supported to put `\node` commands in a `matrix of nodes` or `matrix of math nodes`. Anyway, you seem to use it to give the nodes styles. There is a simpler way. Instead of

```
\node[node style sp] {a_{22}};
```

just say

```
|[node style sp]|  a_{22}
```

This is the method documented in the current manual (v3.1.5) and works.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

% l' unite
\newcommand{\myunit}{1 cm}
\tikzset{
    node style sp/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=\myunit},
    node style ge/.style={circle,minimum size=\myunit},
    arrow style mul/.style={draw,sloped,midway,fill=white},
    arrow style plus/.style={midway,sloped,fill=white},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
% les matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {node style ge},%
             left delimiter  = (,%
             right delimiter = )] at (0,0)
{%
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1p}  \\
  |[node style sp]| a_{21}%
         & |[node style sp]| a_{22}%
                  & \ldots%
                           & |[node style sp]| a_{2p} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{np}  \\
};
\node [draw,below=10pt] at (A.south) 
    { $A$ : \textcolor{red}{$n$ rows} $p$ columns};

\matrix (B) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {node style ge},%
             left delimiter  = (,%
             right delimiter =)] at (6*\myunit,6*\myunit)
{%
  b_{11} & |[node style sp]| b_{12}%
                  & \ldots & b_{1q}  \\
  b_{21} & |[node style sp]| b_{22}%
                  & \ldots & b_{2q}  \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  b_{p1} & |[node style sp]| b_{p2}%
                  & \ldots & b_{pq}  \\
};
\node [draw,above=10pt] at (B.north) 
    { $B$ : $p$ rows \textcolor{red}{$q$ columns}};
% matrice résultat
\matrix (C) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {node style ge},%
             left delimiter  = (,%
             right delimiter = )] at (6*\myunit,0)
{%
  c_{11} & c_{12} & \ldots & c_{1q} \\
  c_{21} & |[node style sp,red]| c_{22}%
                  & \ldots & c_{2q} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  c_{n1} & c_{n2} & \ldots & c_{nq} \\
};
% les fleches
\draw[blue] (A-2-1.north) -- (C-2-2.north);
\draw[blue] (A-2-1.south) -- (C-2-2.south);
\draw[blue] (B-1-2.west)  -- (C-2-2.west);
\draw[blue] (B-1-2.east)  -- (C-2-2.east);
\draw[<->,red](A-2-1) to[in=180,out=90]
  node[arrow style mul] (x) {$a_{21}\times b_{12}$} (B-1-2);
\draw[<->,red](A-2-2) to[in=180,out=90]
  node[arrow style mul] (y) {$a_{22}\times b_{22}$} (B-2-2);
\draw[<->,red](A-2-4) to[in=180,out=90]
  node[arrow style mul] (z) {$a_{2p}\times b_{p2}$} (B-4-2);
\draw[red,->] (x) to node[arrow style plus] {$+$} (y)%
                  to node[arrow style plus] {$+\raisebox{.5ex}{\ldots}+$} (z)%
                  to (C-2-2.north west);

\node [draw,below=10pt] at (C.south) 
    {$ C=A\times B$ : \textcolor{red}{$n$ rows}  \textcolor{red}{$q$ columns}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In 2008 yes it was really supported to put `\node` commands in a `matrix of nodes` ! page 702 59.1   `\node[red]{7}; \draw(0,0) circle(10pt);\\ `

Comment: @AlainMatthes Thanks! I am happy to believe this. At that time I was still using PSTricks. ;-) That means this might have changed.

Comment: The code is in the actual manual !!  And I think it's a mistake in the documentation

Comment: @AlainMatthes My manual (v3.1.5) has stuff about Lindenmayer systems on p. 702. The documentation of **60 Matrix Library** starts on p. 710. But you are right, the example can be found on p. 711, and I agree it should not be there.

Comment: Sorry my manual (v3.1.4) and thanks again!